# How to configure spring with jni?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, java-native-interface

I have requirement to integrate spring with some native code written C and I am new to spring and don't have any idea about it if anybody have experience to integrate spring with JNI then please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is quite vague but I can offer a couple of bits of advice from work I've done in the past.

1. Forget about integrating with "Spring". Concentrate on integrating with Java and let Spring help you out later.
2. Be very, very careful with the types and memory allocation in C
3. [Here](http://www.thirststudios.co.uk/jni.pdf)'s a book on JNI that I found immensely helpful when I was working on it. It's a little dated but still valid
4. I did most of the work in C and then patched in a simple single method hook to Java. That way I did most of the integration with the existing code in its native language.
5. Give your C code a main method that lets you test the C code independently of the Java. Then you can compile your C file as both a library (dll/so) and an executable. The executable can be called on it's own with arguments to test the calls to existing calls.

The general process is.

**Java End**

```
public class statusBlock {
    /* A Java representation of a Status Block */
    private long errcode = 0;
    private long errref = 0;
    private String errmsg = "";
    private long[] TmidArray;
    private long evt_id = 0;
    private short IgViolation_severity = 0;
}

public class MyFunkyJNIClass {
    private Object response;

    /**
     * To generate the C-header for a native call use: javah -jni
     * example.package.MyFunkyJNIClass from target/classes folder.
     */
    private native int nativeExecuteFunction(int callType, Object payload, Object response);

    public MyFunkyJNIClass() {
        System.loadLibrary("theCLibrary");
    }
}
```

In the example above I load the C side of the code using System.loadLibrary and define some fields that I can populate from my C code. To execute just call the *native* function `nativeExecuteFunction(1, "my payload", respObject);` On the C side I can use the first argument to choose what to do. *It simplified my problems at the time*

**C Side**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_example_package_MyFunkyJNIClass_nativeExecuteFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jint CallType, jobject Payload)
{
    // **** JNI Specific declarations for mapping ****
    jclass          cls, cls2, cls3;
    jmethodID       mid, mid2;
    jfieldID        fid;
    jint            rc = 0;
    jsize           js = 0;
    jbyte           jb;
    jobject         jobj, jobj2, jro;
    jobjectArray    jobjArray, jobjArray2;

    _svc_results    results;

    switch ((int)CallType)
    {
    case CALLTYPE1:       // 1
        DEBUG_PRINT("JNI Call Type 1 in progress...\n");
        // JNI mapping happens here
        stat = DoSomethingInC(args, &results);

        // Map from C structure (_statblk) to Java object
        if (stat == SUCCESS) {
            DEBUG_PRINT("\tMapping from C structure (_statblk) to Java object\n");

            cls  = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Lexample/package/statusBlock;");
            mid  = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "()V"); if (mid == NULL) return -1;
            jro  = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, mid); if (jro == NULL) return -1;

            fid  = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "errcode","I"); if (fid == NULL) return -1;
            (*env)->SetIntField(env, jro, fid, (jint)results.statblk.errcode);
            DEBUG_PRINT("\t\tMapped errcode: %d\n",results.statblk.errcode);

            fid  = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "errref","I"); if (fid == NULL) return -1;
            (*env)->SetIntField(env, jro, fid, (jint)results.statblk.errref);
            DEBUG_PRINT("\t\tMapped errref: %d\n",results.statblk.errref);

            fid  = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "errmsg","[B"); if (fid == NULL) return -1;
            jobj = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, MAX_ERR);
            (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, (jbyteArray)jobj, 0, MAX_ERR, (jbyte*)results.statblk.errmsg);
            (*env)->SetObjectField(env, jro, fid, jobj);
            (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jobj);
            DEBUG_PRINT("\t\tMapped errmsg: %s\n",results.statblk.errmsg);

            fid  = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "TmidArray","[I"); if (fid == NULL) return -1;
            jobj = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, (jsize)results.statblk.TmidArray.TmidArray_len);
            (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, (jintArray)jobj, 0, 
                                      (jsize)results.statblk.TmidArray.TmidArray_len,
                                      (jint*)results.statblk.TmidArray.TmidArray_val);
            (*env)->SetObjectField(env, jro, fid, jobj);
            (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jobj);
            DEBUG_PRINT("\t\tMapped TmidArray\n");

            fid  = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "evt_id","I"); if (fid == NULL) return -1;
            (*env)->SetIntField(env, jro, fid, (jint)results.statblk.evt_id);
            DEBUG_PRINT("\t\tMapped evt_id: %d\n",results.statblk.evt_id);

            cls  = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, this);
            fid  = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "response","Ljava/lang/Object;"); if (fid == NULL) return -1;
            (*env)->SetObjectField(env, this, fid, jro);

            DEBUG_PRINT("\tMapping from C structure (_statblk) to Java object - DONE\n");
        } else {
            DEBUG_PRINT("JNI Call Type 1 in progress... Returning Error: %d\n", stat);
            return (jint)stat;
        }

        /* Free our native memory */
        cls  = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, Payload);
        fid  = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "message","Ljava/lang/String;"); if (fid == NULL) return -1;
        jobj = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, Payload, fid);
        GPS_Free(results.statblk.TmidArray.TmidArray_val);
        GPS_Free(results.statblk.ErrorArray.ErrorArray_val);
        DEBUG_PRINT("JNI RTP Posting in progress... DONE\n");
        break;
    case PING:          // 2
        DEBUG_PRINT("No Java to C mapping required\n");
        DEBUG_PRINT("JNI Ping in progress...\n");
        stat = doPing();

        DEBUG_PRINT("No C to Java mapping required\n");
        // Stop null pointer exception if client tries to access the response object.
        cls  = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Lexample/package/EmptySerializableClass;");
        mid  = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "()V"); if (mid == NULL) return -1;
        jro  = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, mid); if (jro == NULL) return -1;

        cls  = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, this);
        fid  = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "response","Ljava/lang/Object;"); if (fid == NULL) return -1;
        (*env)->SetObjectField(env, this, fid, jro);
        DEBUG_PRINT("JNI Ping in progress... DONE\n");

        return (jint)rpc_stat;
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr,"Unknown call type\n");
        rc = -1;
        break;
    }

    return rc;
}
```

I could go on and on, but it just takes a bit of careful reading of that book.

There doesn't really need to be any further integration with Spring. You could stick a `@Component` or `@Service` annotation on the `MyFunkyJNIClass`.

I hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: Thank you very much !! the information provided by you is really useful for me till at this point I am roaming in fog but now I can able to see things from crystal clear glass .

Comment: My question is, how do you make the REST endpoint scale up to handle many requests?

Answer (score 0):

Echoing previous answers that Spring Integration is not really the important thing here. More importantly, is having the JVM interface to your native C/C++ node. Since the question was asked there are a number of online resources available that should help new users to this space.

[JNI Integration walktrough](https://www.baeldung.com/jni)
The Java™ Native Interface: Programmer’s Guide and Specification book is also quite useful
If you really want to go deep then the [official specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) is very helpful